# Decipher receipt data in C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to check if a user has purchased an in-app purchase. This is the only C# I could find (http://www.hassang.com/ios7-xamarin-verifying-and-validating-iap-receipts). When I write this code, I get a long encoded string that doesn't provide any recognizable properties. I feel there is an extra step I should be doing... Any help in C# will be appreciated.

```
NSUrl nsURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.AppStoreReceiptUrl;
NSData receipt = NSData.FromUrl(nsURL);

NSDictionary requestContents = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(
(NSString)receipt
    .GetBase64EncodedString(
        NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None), (NSString)"receipt-data"
);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For details on the formatting and fields within the receipt data returned, see the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: please, my question is about C#. It is mentioned in the title and the body of my question.

Comment: And somehow that means your not using Apple's APIs? Just because your using xamarin doesn't mean your not on Apple's platform.